# Let $A\in M_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be of rank $m$. Choose the correct statement(s) from below:

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in \mathbb{M}_{m\times n}(\mathbb{R})$ be of rank $m$. Choose the correct statement(s) from below:

a)The map $\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^m$ given by $v\to Av$ is injective .

b)There exists matrices $B\in \mathbb{M}_m(\mathbb{R})$ and $C\in \mathbb{M}_m(\mathbb{R})$ such that $BAC=[I_m | \mathbb{O}_{n-m}]$

c)There exists matrices $B\in \mathbb{GL}_m(\mathbb{R})$ and $C\in \mathbb{GL}_m(\mathbb{R})$ such that $BAC=[I_m | \mathbb{O}_{n-m}]$

d)For every $(B,C)\in \mathbb{M}_{m}(\mathbb{R}) \times \mathbb{M}_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $BAC=[I_n| \mathbb{O}_{n-m}]$, $C$ is uniquely  determine by $B$

---

(a) is false as if $m\neq n$ then it cannot be injective.But what we say about else ??For existence of such $B$ matrices how i find such $C$ whcih satisfy it ?? Any help plz ..

Comment: The function $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $f(x)=(x,x)$ is injective…

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos That mapping is not of rank 2.

Comment: Please let us know what you thought about the rest. One poorly reasoned claim is not quite enough context to go on.

Comment: @rschwieb I was just commenting the assertion “(a) is false as if $m\neq n$ then it cannot be injective”.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I see its value to disprove the reasoning in isolation, but we should probably assume the user is working under the hypotheses they gave.  The reasoning is actually half valid, but yes poorly expressed.

Comment: It seems that $n \geqslant m$ was assumed implicitly. Given that $\bolsymbol A$ is of full rank, your claim about $(a)$ is correct. $(d)$ is false, hint: manipulate the zero matrix. P.S. your notation seems not quite correct.